# Map reduce in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have mongo documents in this format.

```
{"_id" : 1,"Summary" : {...},"Examples" : [{"_id" : 353,"CategoryId" : 4},{"_id" : 239,"CategoryId" : 28}, ...  ]}
{"_id" : 2,"Summary" : {...},"Examples" : [{"_id" : 312,"CategoryId" : 2},{"_id" : 121,"CategoryId" : 12}, ...  ]}
```

How can I map/reduce them to get a hash like:

```
{ [ result[categoryId] : count_of_examples , .....] }
```

I.e. count of examples of each category.
I have 30 categories at all, all specified in Categories collection.

Comment: Do you have to use map/reduce or could you move up to 2.1 and use aggregation framework?

Comment: No of course I don't have to use map/reduce. Is there some other way?

Comment: if you can use 2.1 then you can use http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: If you have to do this in 2.0 then you can follow this example to use map/reduce: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use 2.1 (dev version of upcoming release 2.2) then you can use [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation) and it would look something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
       {$project:{"CatId":"$Examples.CategoryId","_id":0}}, 
       {$unwind:"$CatId"}, 
       {$group:{_id:"$CatId","num":{$sum:1} } },  
       {$project:{CategoryId:"$_id",NumberOfExamples:"$num",_id:0  }} 
] );
```

The first step projects the subfield of Examples (CategoryId) into a top level field of a document (not necessary but helps with readability), then we unwind the array of examples which creates a separate document for each array value of CatId, we do a "group by" and count them (I assume each instance of CategoryId is one example, right?) and last we use projection again to relabel the fields and make the result look like this:

```
"result" : [
    {
        "CategoryId" : 12,
        "NumberOfExamples" : 1
    },
    {
        "CategoryId" : 2,
        "NumberOfExamples" : 1
    },
    {
        "CategoryId" : 28,
        "NumberOfExamples" : 1
    },
    {
        "CategoryId" : 4,
        "NumberOfExamples" : 1
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

Comment: I used your example documents so the sums didn't end up being very interesting...

Comment: It sounds great, the other question is how it is implemented in  Mongoid ?

Comment: If you can do db.runCommand then you can use it: db.runCommand({"aggregate":"collectionName", "pipeline":[ ]}) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#aggregate